# Search inside Xournal files (.xoj)

Tags: search, notes, evernote

I'm a big fan of Evernote, I use it regularly. However, it has a 60MB storage limit (although text files are not going to occupy much space, but the limitation concern still remains).

Today, I installed Xournal, which has great features like annotating, nice background, free hand shapes and notes, save in PDF format, and many more. But the big problem is that as far as I've noticed, there is no intrinsic feature for search inside the notes (created using Xournal with .xoj suffix). I used Catfish File Search application (which creates bash commands for full text search), but it couldn't help as well. Is there anyway to search inside a .xoj file at all? If so, it could be a suitable alternative to evernote, if you put your .xoj files on a cloud (which certainly offers you much more storage space than 60MB).

If not, is there any other convenient app similar to Evernote, but with higher storage limit or without a limit? Somebody suggested Zim desktop wiki app, which looks great, but I'm nut sure if I could copy and paste everything there (a mixture of photos and tables and text with various formats and highlights), like what I do with Evernote. And a very useful tool I use is Evernote Web Clipper (browser extension). Of course, having a desktop client like Everpad is a plus, but not the absolute need.

**PS:** I use pocket, so please do suggest that (it only preserve links (which might change over time) not the actual text). I also use google drive or docs, I don't like that  for this purpose neither, it's too slow, doesn't have a browser extension and a desktop client.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Nobody can help?

Answer (score 0):

To search into a Xournal file, you can change its suffix from xoj to gz, then gunzip it. This produces a text (xml) file, that you can search.

Comment: No need to change suffix.  Can directly `zless file.xoj`, `zcat file.xoj | grep TEXT` or `zgrep TEXT file.xoj`.